# I'm integrating google log in in my android applciation and I'm not able to UserName and gender

Tags: android, google-signin

Following is my code In my `onCreate()` method I have done this I have the required permissions and all:

```
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        signIn();
                    }
                });

            GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestEmail().requestProfile().requestScopes(new Scope(PLUS_LOGIN), new Scope(PLUS_ME),
                            new Scope(PROFILE)).requestId().build();
            Plus.PlusOptions options = Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build();
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
                    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME))
                    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(Plus.API, options)
                    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                    .addApi(Plus.API)
                    .build();
            SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
            signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
```

This is my other function where I have got the sign in response:

```
     private void signIn() {
            System.out.println("Inside signIn");
            Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            System.out.println("Inside onActivityResult");
            if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                System.out.println("Inside requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN" + resultCode);
                GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
//I am able to reach here
                System.out.println("After  GoogleSignInResult result" + result);
                if (result.isSuccess()) {
                    System.out.println("Inside isSuccess");
                    GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
                    mFullName = acct.getDisplayName();
                    mEmail = acct.getEmail();
                    System.out.println(acct.describeContents());
                    System.out.println(acct.getGrantedScopes());
                    System.out.println("Result +++++" + result);
                    Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null).setResultCallback(this);
                    Person person = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                    System.out.println("Google Plus name and Email" + mFullName + "  " + mEmail + "   " + person);
//I am getting the person as null in here so i m not abel to get the profile informations and all
                }
            } 
        }
```

I have searched heavily on this and studied all google documents but couldn't find relevant answers for this or if there is any link that can help me over this. I am able to get email id and display name also comes as email id.

Comment: Try to write a [mcve]. Also, read about [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You should include a full desription of what your desired functionality is, what your code currently does, and what you expect it to do. Also post any error messages you get.

Comment: All i want is that i should be able to access profile of someone who log in into my app through google account.